# Bash interactive and non-interactive shell behaviour

Tags: bash, unix, interactive-shell

I have a hard time with interactive and non-interactive shells. I don't understand which is which.

For example, I have read that non interactive shells usually check for the `BASH_ENV` variable on their startup and execute whatever it points to.

So, what I did is I set the `BASH_ENV` to point to some script which only echoes OK. Then I typed in `bash` in terminal and this script echoed OK. But why? Didn't I call yet another INTERACTIVE shell by typing bash in terminal, and not the other way around? Why did it execute the bash_env? I'm on linux mint maya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *only* thing you can be certain of is what's shown in the manpage for `bash` (see `INVOCATION`) - that lists in details what startup files are run in each instance.

However, there's nothing stopping (for example) one of those startup files running *other* files which would normally not be run.

By way of example, if `.bash_profile` had the following line:

```
. ~/.profile
```

it would also run the `.profile` script.

In fact the manpage states:

> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
>
> `if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi`

So, if you put that exact line in your startup scripts for an interactive shell like `~/.bash_profile`, you'll also source the file pointed to by `BASH_ENV`.

Your best bet is to examine the INVOCATION section to find out which of the files will run, and then track through them (with something like `set -x` at the top of the script) to see what's getting called from where.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, Bash is only interactive if you tell it, example

```
bash -i
```

So, by you calling just `bash` you invoked a non-interactive Bash.

More info

```
-i

If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
```

Comment: Not quite. From the manpage: An  interactive  shell  is  one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals. Hence `bash` on its own from a terminal is interactive.